# Vocabulary used in drawing activity diagrams

Tags: time-management, cost-management

In a drawing activity diagram when it says:

`Activity A Follows Activity B`

does it mean `A->B` or `B->A`?

I am confused with this lingo.

Answer (score 3):

Due to your post in PMSE, I assume you are taking about network diagrams (vs. SW-engineering activity diagrams)? For network diagrams, it's like in normal language usage:

- A follows B, so
- A is the successor of B, or
- B is the predecessor of A:
- B -> A

See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_%28project_management%29